# Loop cuts break subsurf

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I sharpen this subsurf (without creating a separate object and parenting it to the current one)?

I'm trying to model this tank :p:

[image]

What I tried:

Adding loop cuts to the mesh but they cut vertically creating ngons (I only want the lower thread "fenders" to be sharpened).

Increasing the crease creates an ugly, broken, deformed mesh.

Is there a better way than creating a separate mesh and parenting it to the current one?

Right now, I'm insetting the lower faces of the fenders and extruding them; the end result is an extruded elliptical plane.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining what you want to harden, exactly. Are you trying to make those oval/cylinder shapes more like rectangular panels?

Comment: Yes. Managed to fix it (added loop cuts over the whole mesh and increased the crease on the outer edges). For some reason it looks ok now.